# remove odd numbers from list

Tags: python

when I run the following code, I did not get the correct answer. It returns [4] when it should return [4, 4].

```
def purify(y):
    new_numbers = []
    for x in y:
            if x%2 ==0:
                    new_numbers.append(x)
        return new_numbers

print(purify([4,5,5,4]))
```

Comment: did you try my solution, if it helped then please accept the answer or vote up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indent is off, place the return after the `for` loop runs

```
def purify(y):
    new_numbers = []
    for x in y:
            if x%2 ==0:
                    new_numbers.append(x)
    return new_numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

Use some elegant expressions like list comprehension combined with `if` something like this

```
def purify(y):
    return [x for x in y if x%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful with indentation when working with Python as below code is good but there is an issue with indentation on `return new_numbers`.

`return new_numbers` is aligned with `if condition` due to which `for loop` only runs once and returns the first `4`. If you indent `return` statement with `for loop` it will work perfectly.

```
def purify(y):
    new_numbers = []
    for x in y:
        if x%2 ==0:
            new_numbers.append(x)
    return new_numbers

print(purify([4,5,5,4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in just one line:

```
def purify(y):    
    return [x for x in y if not x%2]
```

Comment: You might mean `not x%2` so that it returns even numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed! English is not my first language. I have the same problem with right e left!

Answer (score 1):

just use lamda :

```
def purify(y):
 filter(lambda i: not i%2==0, y)
```